# Problems loading from file to arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

So I am writing a quiz program that contains an uncertain # of questions in it (in Java) and I am having problems accomplishing the following things:

1) loading quiz question from file and storing in arraylist and accessing it (need help!)
2) correct answer not accepted - gives me error (logic error)
3) not all answer choices are displayed

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;

public class Quiz {

 public void writeFile() {
   Question qn = new Question();
   try {
     PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("quiz.txt");
     out.println(qn.Question);
     out.println(qn.numberOfChoices);
     qn.answerChoices = new String[qn.numberOfChoices];
     for (int i = 0; i < qn.numberOfChoices; i++) {
         out.println(qn.answerChoices[i]);
     }
     out.println(qn.correctAnswer);
     out.println(qn.numOfTries);
     out.println(qn.numOfCorrectTries);
     out.close();
   } catch (IOException f) {
     System.out.println("Error.");
   }
   qn.getQuestion();
 }

 public void readFile() {
     File file = new File ("quiz.txt");
     boolean exists = file.exists();
     Quiz q = new Quiz();
     Question a = new Question();
     List<String> question = new ArrayList<String>();
     String[] answerChoices = a.answerChoices;
     try {
        if (exists == true) {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
            a.Question = s.nextLine();
            a.numberOfChoices = s.nextInt();
            a.answerChoices = new String[a.numberOfChoices];
            for (int i = 0; i < a.numberOfChoices; i++) {
                a.answerChoices[i] = s.nextLine();
            }
            s.nextLine();
            a.correctAnswer = s.nextInt();
            a.numOfTries = s.nextInt();
            a.numOfCorrectTries = s.nextInt();
            a.getQuestion();
         } else {
            q.writeFile();
         }
     } catch (IOException e) {
       System.out.println("File not found.");
     }
 }

public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Quiz qz = new Quiz();
    Question b = new Question();
    int Selection;
    List<String> question = new ArrayList<String>();

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Quiz Program! Good luck!");
    do {
       qz.readFile();
       System.out.println("Your answer?: ");
       Selection = in.nextInt();
       if (Selection == b.correctAnswer) {
          b.numOfCorrectTries++;
          b.getQuestion();
       } else {
          b.getQuestion();
       }
    } while (Selection < b.numberOfChoices);
    while (Selection > b.numberOfChoices || Selection < 0) {
       System.out.println("Error. Try again");
       System.out.println("Your answer?: ");
       Selection = in.nextInt();
    }
  }
}
```

and the question class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;

public class Question {

 int correctAnswer;
 int numOfTries;
 int numOfCorrectTries;
 int numberOfChoices;
 String Question;
 String[] answerChoices;

 public Question() {

 }
 public void getQuestion() {
    System.out.println("Question: " + Question);
    System.out.println("Answer: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChoices; i++) {
        System.out.println(answerChoices[i]);
    }
 }

 public double getPercentageRight() {
     double percentageRight = (numOfCorrectTries / numOfTries) * 100;
     percentageRight = Math.round(percentageRight * 100);
     percentageRight = percentageRight / 100;
     return percentageRight;
 }
}
```

QUIZ.TXT:

```
How many licks does it take to get to the tootsie roll center of a  
tootsie pop?
4
one
two
three
four
2
14
5
What is your name?
3
Arthur, King of the Britons
Sir Lancelot the Brave
Sir Robin the Not-Quite-So-Brave-As-Sir Lancelot
0
14
6
Who's on first?
5
What
Why
Because
Who
I don't know
3
14
7
Which of the following is a terror of the fire swamp?
4
Lightning sand
Flame spurt
R.O.U.S.
All of the above
3
14
4
Who is the all-time greatest pilot?
6
Manfred von Richthofen
Chuck Yeager
Hiraku Sulu
Luke Skywalker
Kara Thrace
Charles Lindbergh
4
14
9
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors when this code runs?

Comment: I don't get runtime or compiler error at least for now. it's just not displaying all of the choices when I load the question. it also gives me error when I put the right answer. so essentially a logic error.

Comment: Can you include a sample `quiz.txt` file?

Comment: there's a quiz.txt file here.

Comment: Can you just specify how you need the output of your java program of this quiz thing???

Answer (score 1):

Some issues:

Your `List<String> question = new ArrayList<String>();` should instead be something like `List<Question> questionBank = new ArrayList<Question>();` since holding everything as a string (instead of a Question object) would be significantly messier. The name `questionBank` is also more descriptive than `question` when reading the code. I would also recommend having the `questionBank` as a class variable so it's easily accessible throughout your `Quiz` class.

You never add the questions to your ArrayList but I suspect you already know that and it was just low priority while fixing the other issues.

Your `Question` class is also a bit unconventional. A better way to structure it might be something like this:

```
public class Question {

     private int correctAnswer;
     private int numOfTries;
     private int numOfCorrectTries;
     private String question;
     private String[] answerChoices;

     public Question(String question, String[] answerChoices,
             int correctAnswer, int numOfTries, int numOfCorrectTries) {
         this.question = question;
         this.answerChoices = answerChoices;
         this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
         this.numOfTries = numOfTries;
         this.numOfCorrectTries = numOfCorrectTries;
     }

     public void getQuestion() {
            System.out.println("Question: " + question);
            System.out.println("Answer: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < answerChoices.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(answerChoices[i]);
            }
     }

     public double getPercentageRight() {
         double percentageRight = (numOfCorrectTries / numOfTries) * 100;
         percentageRight = Math.round(percentageRight * 100);
         percentageRight = percentageRight / 100;
         return percentageRight;
     }

}
```

I removed the variable for `numberOfChoices` since that is the same as `answerChoices.length`. I also renamed your `Question` to `question` since variables in Java usually follow camelCase. I'm not sure what the other methods are for or how they should display output so I mostly left them alone.

For reading to a file I think you can do something similar to what you have, but I'll post the code I have that conforms to the new constructor for the `Question` class.

```
private void addQuestions() {
    File quizText = new File("quiz.txt");
    try {
        Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(quizText);
        while (fileIn.hasNextLine()) {
            String question = fileIn.nextLine();
            int numberOfAnswers = fileIn.nextInt();
            fileIn.nextLine();
            String[] answers = new String[numberOfAnswers];
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfAnswers; i++) {
                answers[i] = fileIn.nextLine();
            }
            int correctAnswer = fileIn.nextInt();
            int numOfTries = fileIn.nextInt();
            int numOfCorrectTries = fileIn.nextInt();
            fileIn.nextLine();
            Question nextQuestion =
                new Question(question, answers, correctAnswer, numOfTries, numOfCorrectTries);
            questionBank.add(nextQuestion);
        }
        fileIn.close();
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("File Not Found.");
        return;
    }
}
```

I also made the variables private but you can create a custom getter for them to prevent them from being directly accessed (and/or changed) from the outside. Using this code I was able to create a question bank with all five questions and display the correct answer along with all possible choices so hopefully it points you in the right direction.

Comment: I use List<Question> questionBank = new List<Question> questionBank, but there's an argument mismatch, how would I solve this problem? And also, I load the questions from a file successfully and their answer choices and stuff, but I am not sure how to store them in the arrayList and/or access them from the arrayList. I was wondering how to do this successfully

Comment: Since you want an ArrayList you should initialize it like this `List<Question> questionBank = new ArrayList<>();` And I strongly recommend making it a class variable so you can access it from within the `addQuestions()` method. Using the method as I described above will store the `Question` objects inside the `ArrayList`. If you want to access the information from the `Question` class you need to create methods inside that class to do so.

Comment: I did, but what if I wanted to put that in my Quiz class instead of my Question class?

Comment: The ArrayList definitely belongs in your Quiz class.

Comment: So looking at the code, do I need a for loop in my addQuestion() class to add all of the questions to the question class and accessing them. I feel like it might help, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The `addQuestion()` method I wrote above already scans the text file as long as there's still input and the line `questionBank.add(nextQuestion)` adds the question to the `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

I re-did you quiz class. In my example all your questions stated above is answered. I'll explain them one by one.

```
public class Quiz {

List<Question> question = new ArrayList<Question>();

public void writeFile() {
    Question qn = new Question();
    try {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("quiz.txt");
        out.println(qn.Question);
        out.println(qn.numberOfChoices);
        qn.answerChoices = new String[qn.numberOfChoices];
        for (int i = 0; i < qn.numberOfChoices; i++) {
            out.println(qn.answerChoices[i]);
        }
        out.println(qn.correctAnswer);
        out.println(qn.numOfTries);
        out.println(qn.numOfCorrectTries);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException f) {
        System.out.println("Error.");
    }
    qn.getQuestion();
}

public void readFile() {
    File file = new File("quiz.txt");
    boolean exists = file.exists();
    Quiz q = new Quiz();
    Question a = new Question();
    String[] answerChoices;
    try {
        if (exists == true) {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
            String line = "";
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                line = s.nextLine();
                if (line.startsWith("---")) {
                    a = new Question();
                    a.Question = line.substring(4);
                } else if (line.startsWith("choices : ")) {
                    a.numberOfChoices = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(10).trim());
                    a.answerChoices = new String[a.numberOfChoices];
                    for (int i = 0; i < a.numberOfChoices; i++) {
                        a.answerChoices[i] = s.nextLine();
                    }
                } else if (line.startsWith("correct answer : ")) {
                    a.correctAnswer = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(17).trim());

                } else if (line.startsWith("No of Tries : ")) {
                    a.numOfTries = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(14).trim());

                } else if (line.startsWith("No of correct Tries : ")) {
                    a.numOfCorrectTries = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(22).trim());
                    question.add(a);
                }
            }
        } else {
            q.writeFile();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Quiz qz = new Quiz();
    qz.readFile();
    Question b = new Question();
    int selection;

    //real program starts here
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Quiz Program! Good luck!");
    System.out.println("****************************************");

    b = qz.question.get(2); // you can implement how your questions are taken from list of questions
    b.getQuestion();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Your answer?: ");
    selection = in.nextInt();

    if (selection == b.correctAnswer) {
        b.numOfCorrectTries++;
        System.out.println("Correct answer");

    } else {
        System.out.println("Incorrect answer");
    }
}

}
```

**1) loading quiz question from file and storing in arraylist and accessing it (need help!)**

Instead of using

```
 List<String> question = new ArrayList<String>();
```

use below as class variable. So you can access them anywhere inside your class

```
 List<Question> question = new ArrayList<Question>();
```

**2) correct answer not accepted - gives me error (logic error)**

Logic is corrected in the main block.

**3) not all answer choices are displayed**

Re-did you readFile() method. but to be success with this logic you need to recreate your quiz.txt as below.

```
--- How many licks does it take to get to the tootsie roll center of a tootsie pop?
choices : 4
one
two
three
four
correct answer : 2
No of Tries : 14
No of correct Tries : 5
--- What is your name?
choices : 3
Arthur, King of the Britons
Sir Lancelot the Brave
Sir Robin the Not-Quite-So-Brave-As-Sir Lancelot
correct answer : 0
No of Tries : 14
No of correct Tries : 6
--- Who's on first?
choices : 5
What
Why
Because
Who
I don't know
correct answer :  3
No of Tries : 14
No of correct Tries : 7
--- Which of the following is a terror of the fire swamp?
choices : 4
Lightning sand
Flame spurt
R.O.U.S.
All of the above
correct answer : 3
No of Tries : 14
No of correct Tries : 4
--- Who is the all-time greatest pilot?
choices : 6
Manfred von Richthofen
Chuck Yeager
Hiraku Sulu
Luke Skywalker
Kara Thrace
Charles Lindbergh
correct answer : 4
No of Tries : 14
No of correct Tries : 9
```

**Note :**
Selection of the question is based on

```
   b = qz.question.get(2);
```

in the main(). To create a question paper based on randomly selected questions, you might create a separate method and prompt questions from this method. Refer Math.random() further.

**Also better to create an XML file instead of txt for this kind of applications. Google for "Java and XML"**

Hope this helps.